# Read large Excel file .xlsx

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, sax

i'm using library

```
org.apache.poi 


XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
```

I'm trying

```
org.xml.sax
```

library, but cannot able convert it into workbook

NOTE : at end result i want XSSFWorkbook to be returned

the above code will go out of memory, any help will be appreciated
ThankQ in advance

Comment: "NOTE : at end result i want XSSFWorkbook to be returned": That's not possible. XSSFWorkbook needs to be fully in memory. Try using SXSSFWorkbook https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf.

Comment: The question talks about reading, not writing, which SXSSFWorkbook is all about.

Answer (score 2):

If the input data is too large for the available memory, you have two options.

a) Provide more memory via the -Xmx java command line option

b) Use the [Streaming-API of POI](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api).

Option a) will be easy to do if the files eventually fit in memory. If the file is too large for the available physical memory, you will need to take a look at the streaming options, especially the sample [XLSX2CSV](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java) shows how you can read data from arbitrarily large .xlsx files, albeit with some features that need to access multiple cells not available out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("yourXLSX file path"));
Workbook workbook = StreamingReader.builder().rowCacheSize(100).bufferSize(4096).open(is))
for (Sheet sheet: workbook) {
    //System.out.println(sheet.getSheetName());
    for (Row r: sheet) {
        for (Cell c: r) {
            //System.out.println(c.getStringCellValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But this has limitations- it throws unsupported exception for getPhysicalRows, getRow etc lots of unsupported methods