# how read excel file having more than 100000 row in java?

Tags: java, excel, string, collections, apache-poi

I am trying read excel file having more than 100000 rows in java using apache poi. but I am encountering few problems.

1-) It is taking 10 to 15 min in fetching data from excel file.

2-) As I run my code, my laptop starts hanging. Because of that it is became difficult to fetch data and then I have to restart my laptop.

Is there any other way by which I can fetch data from my excel file in less time using java ??

Here is my current code:

```
public class ReadRfdsDump {

    public void readRfdsDump() {
        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\esatnir\\Videos\\sprint\\sprintvision.sprint.com_Trackor Browser_RF Design Sheet_07062018122740.xlsx"));
             XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
             XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
             DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();

             for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
                 Row row= sheet.getRow(i);
                 System.out.println(df.formatCellValue(row.getCell(1)));
             }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `SXXFWorkBook` instead of `XXFWorkBook`

Comment: Reading 100,000 rows ought to take no more than a few seconds, see the Apache POI FAQ for details!

Comment: how to use  SXXFWorkBook for read excel file. can you show me link or something ??

Comment: Format the code a better way, and fix some issue in the question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36473062/read-large-excel-file-xlsx

Comment: i have tried your link still i am  not able to fetch data of specific row and column of my excel. it is printing all the data of my excel file together. how can i able to get data of specific row and column ??

Comment: https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader is one option - also see https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java#L89

Answer (score 3):

`Apache poi`'s default opening a workbook using `WorkbookFactory.create` or `new XSSFWorkbook` will always parsing the whole workbook inclusive all sheets. If the workbook contains much data this leads to high memory usage. Opening the workbook using a `File` instead of a `InputStream` decreases the memory usage. But this leads to other problems since the used file then cannot be overwritten, at least not when `*.xlsx` files.

There is [XSSF and SAX (Event API)](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api) which get at the underlying XML data, and process using `SAX`.

But if we are already at this level where we get at the underlying XML data, and process it, then we could go one more step back too.

A `*.xlsx` file is a `ZIP` archive containing the data in `XML` files within a directory structure. So we can unzip the `*.xlsx` file and get the data from the `XML` files then.

There is `/xl/sharedStrings.xml` having all the string cell values in it. And there is `/xl/workbook.xml` describing the workbook structure. And there are `/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml`, `/xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml`, ... which are storing the sheets' data. And there is `/xl/styles.xml` having the style settings for all cells in the sheets.

So all we need is working with `ZIP` file system using `Java`. This is supported using [java.nio.file.FileSystems](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html).

And we need a possibility for parsing `XML`. There [Package javax.xml.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/package-summary.html) is my favorite.

The following shows a working draft. It parses the `/xl/sharedStrings.xml`. Also it parses the `/xl/styles.xml`. But it gets only the number formats and the cell number format settings. The number format settings are essential for detecting date / time values. It then parses the `/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml` which contains the data of the first sheet. For detecting whether a number format is a date format, and so the formatted cell contains a date / time value, one single `apache poi` class `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil` is used. This is done to simplify the code. Of course even this class we could have coded ourself.

```
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.FileSystem;

import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.stream.events.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;

public class UnZipAndReadXLSXFileSystem {

 public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception {

  XMLEventReader reader = null;
  XMLEvent event = null;
  Attribute attribute = null;
  StartElement startElement = null; 
  EndElement endElement = null; 

  String characters = null;
  StringBuilder stringValue = new StringBuilder(); //for collecting the characters to complete values 

  List<String> sharedStrings = new ArrayList<String>(); //list of shared strings

  Map<String, String> numberFormats = new HashMap<String, String>(); //map of number formats
  List<String> cellNumberFormats = new ArrayList<String>(); //list of cell number formats

  Path source = Paths.get("ExcelExample.xlsx"); //path to the Excel file

  FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(source, null); //get filesystem of Excel file

  //get shared strings ==============================================================================
  Path sharedStringsTable = fs.getPath("/xl/sharedStrings.xml");
  reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventReader(Files.newInputStream(sharedStringsTable));
  boolean siFound = false;
  while (reader.hasNext()) {
   event = (XMLEvent)reader.next();
   if (event.isStartElement()){
    startElement = (StartElement)event;
    if (startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("si")) {
     //start element of shared string item
     siFound = true;
     stringValue = new StringBuilder();
    } 
   } else if (event.isCharacters() && siFound) {
    //chars of the shared string item
    characters = event.asCharacters().getData();
    stringValue.append(characters);
   } else if (event.isEndElement() ) {
    endElement = (EndElement)event;
    if (endElement.getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("si")) {
     //end element of shared string item
     siFound = false;
     sharedStrings.add(stringValue.toString());
    }
   }
  }
  reader.close();
System.out.println(sharedStrings);
  //shared strings ==================================================================================

  //get styles, number formats are essential for detecting date / time values =======================
  Path styles = fs.getPath("/xl/styles.xml");
  reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventReader(Files.newInputStream(styles));
  boolean cellXfsFound = false;
  while (reader.hasNext()) {
   event = (XMLEvent)reader.next();
   if (event.isStartElement()){
    startElement = (StartElement)event;
    if (startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("numFmt")) {
     //start element of number format
     attribute = startElement.getAttributeByName(new QName("numFmtId"));
     String numFmtId = attribute.getValue();
     attribute = startElement.getAttributeByName(new QName("formatCode"));
     numberFormats.put(numFmtId, ((attribute != null)?attribute.getValue():"null"));
    } else if (startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("cellXfs")) {
     //start element of cell format setting
     cellXfsFound = true;

    } else if (startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("xf") && cellXfsFound ) {
     //start element of format setting in cell format setting
     attribute = startElement.getAttributeByName(new QName("numFmtId"));
     cellNumberFormats.add(((attribute != null)?attribute.getValue():"null"));
    }
   } else if (event.isEndElement() ) {
    endElement = (EndElement)event;
    if (endElement.getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("cellXfs")) {
     //end element of cell format setting
     cellXfsFound = false;
    }
   }
  }
  reader.close();
System.out.println(numberFormats);
System.out.println(cellNumberFormats);
  //styles ==========================================================================================

  //get sheet data of first sheet ===================================================================
  Path sheet1 = fs.getPath("/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml");
  reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventReader(Files.newInputStream(sheet1));
  boolean rowFound = false;
  boolean cellFound = false;
  boolean cellValueFound = false;
  boolean inlineStringFound = false; 
  String cellStyle = null;
  String cellType = null;
  while (reader.hasNext()) {
   event = (XMLEvent)reader.next();
   if (event.isStartElement()){
    startElement = (StartElement)event;
    if (startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("row")) {
     //start element of row
     rowFound = true;
System.out.print("<Row");

     attribute = startElement.getAttributeByName(new QName("r"));
System.out.print(" r=" + ((attribute != null)?attribute.getValue():"null"));
System.out.println(">");

    } else if (startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("c") && rowFound) {
     //start element of cell in row
     cellFound = true;
System.out.print("<Cell");

     attribute = startElement.getAttributeByName(new QName("r"));
System.out.print(" r=" + ((attribute != null)?attribute.getValue():"null"));

     attribute = startElement.getAttributeByName(new QName("t"));
System.out.print(" t=" + ((attribute != null)?attribute.getValue():"null"));
     cellType = ((attribute != null)?attribute.getValue():null);

     attribute = startElement.getAttributeByName(new QName("s"));
System.out.print(" s=" + ((attribute != null)?attribute.getValue():"null"));
     cellStyle = ((attribute != null)?attribute.getValue():null);

System.out.print(">");

    } else if (startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("v") && cellFound) {
     //start element of value in cell
     cellValueFound = true;
System.out.print("<V>");
     stringValue = new StringBuilder();

    } else if (startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("is") && cellFound) {
     //start element of inline string in cell
     inlineStringFound = true;
System.out.print("<Is>");
     stringValue = new StringBuilder();

    }
   } else if (event.isCharacters() && cellFound && (cellValueFound || inlineStringFound)) {
    //chars of the cell value or the inline string
    characters = event.asCharacters().getData();
    stringValue.append(characters);

   } else if (event.isEndElement()) {
    endElement = (EndElement)event;
    if (endElement.getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("row")) {
     //end element of row
     rowFound = false;
System.out.println("</Row>");

    } else if (endElement.getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
     //end element of cell
     cellFound = false;
System.out.println("</Cell>");

    } else if (endElement.getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("v")) {
     //end element of value
     cellValueFound = false;

     String cellValue = stringValue.toString();

     if ("s".equals(cellType)) {
      cellValue = sharedStrings.get(Integer.valueOf(cellValue));
     }

     if (cellStyle != null) {
      int s = Integer.valueOf(cellStyle);
      String formatIndex = cellNumberFormats.get(s);
      String formatString = numberFormats.get(formatIndex);
      if (DateUtil.isADateFormat(Integer.valueOf(formatIndex), formatString)) {
       double dDate = Double.parseDouble(cellValue); 
       Date date = DateUtil.getJavaDate(dDate);
       cellValue = date.toString();
      }
     }

System.out.print(cellValue);
System.out.print("</V>");

    } else if (endElement.getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("is")) {
     //end element of inline string
     inlineStringFound = false;

     String cellValue = stringValue.toString();
System.out.print(cellValue);
System.out.print("</Is>");

    }
   }
  }
  reader.close();
  //sheet data ======================================================================================

  fs.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: can i be able to fetch data of specific row and column by using your code ??

Comment: @George.S: As said, it is a working draft. But it is commented and the `System.out.print...` should show you where you can start determining which row and cell you currently have. Of course you need understand how the code works. It is not a ready to use code.

Answer (score 0):

*Apache POI* is your friend - this is correct. But I faced with OutOfMemory when I read very big Excel with formulas.

My solution. If you want to only read data from **XLSX** file, and do not worry about formulas, then do read it as **simple xml** file and extract data from it (it us pretty easy).

1. Read your *.xlsx file as zip archive
2. Got to `xl\worksheets` folder and you find one xml file per one sheet
3. Read this file using any xml reader and retrieve data you need